# Facebook SSO problems with iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook to my app, I've implemented the SSO feature, however I ran into a bit of a snag, once I quit the app I am unable to restore the user's session. I store the token and expiry date as shown:

```
-(void)fbDidLogin {
NSString *tokenString = [[self facebook] accessToken];
NSDate * expirationDate = [[self facebook] expirationDate];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: tokenString forKey:@"FacebookToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: expirationDate forKey:@"FacebookExpirationDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"Login");
```

}

this is the delegate method called upon successful login.

and resume the session:

```
  NSString *tokenString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FacebookToken"];    
NSDate *expDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FacebookExpirationDate"];
if (tokenString != nil && expDate != nil)
{
    [[facebookFetcher facebook]setAccessToken:tokenString];
    [[facebookFetcher facebook] setExpirationDate:expDate];
}
if ([[facebookFetcher facebook]  isSessionValid])
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Bummer");
}
```

I've tried tackling the problem  in a number of ways without luck. One thing I've noticed is that the expiry date seems to be a bit weird:**4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000** Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is at the following link

[Does the Facebook iOS SDK require the user to authenticate every time they use the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571648/does-the-facebook-ios-sdk-require-the-user-to-authenticate-every-time-they-use-th)

Comment: If it's a duplicate of another question, you should (also) flag it for moderator attention saying it's a duplicate. I don't know enough about iOS's Facebook API to judge, but your answer implies it's a duplicate... (Duplicate questions are frowned upon)

Answer (score 0):

The date **4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000** is seen when using the extended permission **offline_access**.

I ran into trouble with this because I was converting the date into "seconds since 1970" like how it's done on the Android Facebook SDK.  If you convert 4001-01-01 to seconds using `NSDate`'s `timeIntervalSince1970`, you'll get a negative number (-2147483648), so watch out.