# Facebook login in Titanium SSO giving error with code "-1"

Tags: ios, facebook, titanium

I have a problem with login with facebook in my Titanium app for iOS.
I'm using Titanium SDK 3.4.0.
If I set forceDialogAuth = true, everything works.
If I set forceDialogAuth = false but I have not stored account information in iOS settings, it works with and without Facebook app installed.
If the account is stored, it gives me success=0 with code=-1.
I think there is some problem with app configuration on Facebook side, but I really cannot understand where. I have appID, I set my app bundleName, I turned on SSO, I declared app native in advanced.
What I might be missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please check [titanium-ios-facebook error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445233/titanium-ios-facebook-sso-not-returning-to-app?rq=1)

Comment: I already set correct bundleId, a valid appstoreid (from another app, because this is not published yet) and enabled sso in facebook application.